# Google Tag Manager... Will data layer for server side rendering override the data layer for web?

Tags: google-tag-manager, google-tag-manager-server-side

I am looking to add server side rendering for google tag mananger. We already have web rendering, and if I just add another for server side will it override the data layer?

web layer: https://developers.google.com/tag-platform/tag-manager/web/datalayer

server layer: https://developers.google.com/tag-platform/tag-manager/server-side/send-data

current code:

so will `window.dataLayer.push({ event: name })` go to both or it will only go to 1?

I tried reading the documentation but it wasn't clear

Answer (score 0):

It will go both of the container.

Since server side is waiting sending data from your webiste.

The DataLayer is kind of something providing the information.

```
DataLayer -> GTM Web container -> GA, GA4, Other market tool.

DataLayer -> GTM Web container or other way -> GTM Server container
```

The rough direction should be above.